# "children were sold to sweep the chimney" is it a valid structure

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

> During that time **children were sold to sweep the chimney.**

Here, the two works-- 1. **selling**, 2. **sweeping** are being done by **two different people / group of people.**

> **The pencil is used to write something.**

Here in the second example, both of the  **works--** 1. **using**, 2. **writing** are being done by the same person.

I'm confused about the **first sentence** and 
I heard the it from someone. Is the sentence valid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your sentence is common, valid and clear, though occasionally that construction *could* be ambiguous. Where it is unclear, the sentence should be rewritten. Here are some similar examples.

- "I bought a radio to play music." [I'm not making music, the radio is.]
- "She sold brooms to sweep leaves." [She is not sweeping the leaves.]

BUT

- "She sold brooms to buy a car." [Clearly, she wants to buy a car.]